# Install APC/eaccelerator and Memcached php-extensions on shared hosting

Tags: cache, shared-hosting, php, opcode

let's say I want to improve my application's performances.And I want to use an Opcode cache tool such as APC or eaccelerator and apply variable caching using Memcached.
Let's say then I'm a beginner and I have built a working-app using the above specifications.

When I need to publish my site (remote) and I'm looking around for the best "hosting solution" **which host-parameters should I care about when it comes to install php extensions such those for my caching tools?Is it even possible to do that using a shared host?**

I'm working on a windows environment but I read that Installing such caching tools (or whatever) on Linux server I need to **type few commands within a shell**..Do this mean host should provide me with a shell window?I'm very confused about this topic.

Hope you can help me out

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1):

Shared hosting providers are basic, very basic, and unless you're very lucky to get an outstanding one it's unlikely they'll install any custom software beyond a basic LAMP stack. And no shared hosting provider will give you a shell with permissions to install software (Known as 'root').

Sounds like your app would be much better suited to a decent VPS (Virtual Private Server) provider. VPS basically gives you all the features you would expect from a full dedicated server* but it's cheaper because the host will run multiple 'virtualized' servers on the same physical box.

If you're not that familiar with Linux I'd advise you go for a managed solution. I'd suggest LiquidWeb as their support service will fit your requirements perfectly. They look after everything, if your server goes down at 2AM they fix it and if you need any software installed just ask them and they'll do it. They even have a "best effort" policy on software installs so even if it's software they've never used before their support guys will spend up to 45 mins trying to install it. But even better, they'll give your root access so you can go in yourself and get a terminal to install software and play with settings safe in the knowledge that if you screw stuff up they can come in and fix it =)

In the interest of fairness, there are many good VPS providers around; SliceHost, Dataflame, and about 100 others but I've only had experience with LiquidWeb.